# SwiftUI List crashes when adding items on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, thread-safety

I'm experiencing some issues when adding items to a SwiftUI `List` that causes a crash/freeze-up with the error:

```
NSOutlineView error inserting child indexes <NSIndexSet: 0x600003401ea0>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (10)] in parent 0x0 (which has 9 children).
```

I built the app using Xcode 14 Beta 3, and I was able to reproduce this issue on `macOS Monterey` and `macOS Ventura Beta 3`.

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

```swift
struct MyData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data: [MyData] = []
    @State var selection = Set<UUID>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data, selection: $selection) { item in
                Text(item.text)
            }
            
            Button("Press Me!") {
                DispatchQueue(label: "Worker").async {
                    for i in 0..<500 {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            data.append(MyData(text: String(i)))
                        }
                        
                        usleep(100_000) // 0.1 seconds
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the app is just an empty Sidebar. When you press the button, a worker thread starts and it adds a new item to the Sidebar every 0.1 seconds.

You can reproduce the example like this:

1. Run the app
2. Press the "Press Me!" button
3. As the items flow into the Sidebar, **start randomly selecting some of those items in the Sidebar. Scrolling at the same time also helps in reproducing this issue.**
4. Eventually, the app should lock up and an error message should appear in the console.

This looks just like a threading issue, except for the fact that all updates to `data` are wrapped in `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

[This is a link to a video which shows this issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HhGu.gif)

#### What I've tried

1. I've tried replacing the `DispatchQueue` with `Task` and `Task.detached`, and using `try await Task.sleep` instead of `usleep`, but this doesn't seem to help at all.
2. I've tried moving the work and `data` into a separate `ViewModel` class. The same issue occurs.
3. I've tried using `Timer.scheduledTimer` instead of running in a background queue, and this actually works. However, in my real code base, I'm actually processing an `AsyncStream` that continuously emits data. The `usleep` in the MRE is just to simulate work.

I'm really puzzled as to what's going on. It looks like this code is thread safe, but `Timer.scheduledTimer` works and it callbacks on the main queue.
Does anyone know why this issue is occurring?

Could this be an issue with SwiftUI internally? If so, are there any workarounds to alleviate this issue?

**Update:**  [This post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708592) mentions a warning

> Update NavigationAuthority bound path tried to update multiple times per frame

Which is similar to some of the log messages I'm also getting. They also mention how the app often freezes when navigated with a `NavigationLink`, similar to this issue.

Comment: I reproduced you code and after specifying a `.default` quality-of-service for `DispatchQueue`, it seems like the issue is gone for some reason. Try it!

Comment: @AgentBilly I changed the code to `DispatchQueue(label: "Worker", qos: .default)`, but the issue remains still. This is one weird problem :P

Comment: Oh it turns out I didn't click rapid enough...

Comment: I could reproduce your problem, using your code and my tests code. Looks like `NavigationView` and the new derivatives (NavigationStack, NavigationSplitView) are very buggy on macos.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Thank you for your help on this! I think I might just submit a feedback report

Comment: Ii have a similar issue updating a list with data from swift data. It works fine on iOS but hangs on macOS. Did you get any update to this?